# Why wifi in HP 15 envy series laptop goes down frequently

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I just received my HP laptop with Windows 8 yesterday and I am learning the new Envy.

However, I observed that my Wifi goes down very frequently. (I checked on my other laptop which runs Windows 7 where I do not see any issue)

I am not sure if its just a setting issue or issue with my laptop itself.

Can someone help me what all the items I should be looking at to get this working myself?

Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the hP customer service

I was told they are hearing about this intermittent WIFI issues on their ENVY 15 and 17 series. (May be a particular batch of production have issues)

If you plan to buy one you should be looking out for this.
I have talked to them and got a replacement order placed for a 14" now.